# How to access properties of Get-ChildItem Registry output

Tags: powershell

Using the below code, I get `Name` & `LastLogon` populated, but not `ProfilePath`.

`Add-RegKeyMember` is https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Get-Last-Write-Time-and-06dcf3fb .

I have tried to access `ProfileImagePath` with `$Profile.Properties.ProfileImagePath`, `$Profile.Name.ProfileImagePath`, and others, but they all return blank (could be null). How on earth is this seemingly object making these properties available?

```
$Profiles = get-childitem "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList" | Add-RegKeyMember

foreach($Profile in $Profiles)
{

  $ThisProfileInfo = @{Name=$Profile.Name;
                     LastLogon=$Profile.LastWriteTime;
                     ProfilePath=$Profile.ProfileImagePath}
  $Profile
}

Name                           Property                                                                                                                                                       
----                           --------                                                                                                                                                       
S-1-5-18                       Flags            : 12                                                                                                                                          
                               ProfileImagePath : C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile                                                                                                    
                               RefCount         : 1                                                                                                                                           
                               Sid              : {1, 1, 0, 0...}                                                                                                                             
                               State            : 0
```

Comment: Put this in the loop: `($Profile | Get-ItemProperty).ProfileImagePath` to get what you need actually, and it's as simple as that to get what you need. Easy and simple!

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Working with Registry Entries](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/samples/working-with-registry-entries?view=powershell-7) for more detail, but the **`Win32.RegistryKey`** type doesn't contain all the data for the values in that key, just the "**Property**" *NoateProperty* that lists the value names.

```
$ProfilePath = 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList'
$Profiles = Get-ChildItem $PRofilePath
$Profiles | Get-Member -MemberType NoteProperty
```

```
   TypeName: Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey

Name          MemberType   Definition
----          ----------   ----------
Property      NoteProperty string[] Property=System.String[]
PSChildName   NoteProperty string PSChildName=S-1-5-18
...
```

To view key entries & their values, you can use **`Get-ItemProperty`**:

```
$Profiles | Get-ItemProperty | select * -Exclude PS*
```

```
Flags            : 12
ProfileImagePath : C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile
RefCount         : 1
Sid              : {1, 1, 0, 0...}
State            : 0

Flags            : 0
ProfileImagePath : C:\WINDOWS\ServiceProfiles\LocalService
State            : 0

Flags            : 0
ProfileImagePath : C:\WINDOWS\ServiceProfiles\NetworkService
State            : 0

ProfileImagePath                        : C:\Users\keith
Flags                                   : 0
State                                   : 0
Sid                                     : {1, 5, 0, 0...}
FullProfile                             : 1
Migrated                                : {96, 248, 201, 91...}
LocalProfileLoadTimeLow                 : 3360357489
LocalProfileLoadTimeHigh                : 30847106
ProfileAttemptedProfileDownloadTimeLow  : 0
ProfileAttemptedProfileDownloadTimeHigh : 0
ProfileLoadTimeLow                      : 0
ProfileLoadTimeHigh                     : 0
RunLogonScriptSync                      : 0
LocalProfileUnloadTimeLow               : 1652511590
LocalProfileUnloadTimeHigh              : 30847106

ProfileImagePath : C:\Users\LongUserName
Flags            : 0
State            : 4
Sid              : {1, 5, 0, 0...}
FullProfile      : 1
Migrated         : {144, 179, 238, 90...}

ProfileImagePath : C:\Users\Administrator
Flags            : 0
State            : 4
Sid              : {1, 5, 0, 0...}
FullProfile      : 1
Migrated         : {96, 87, 195, 93...}
```

An alternate way to access the data, and likely the better choice in your case, is the **`RegistryKey.GetValue()`** method of the **`Win32.RegistryKey`**. So your code would become:

```
...
foreach($Profile in $Profiles)
{

  $ThisProfileInfo = @{
      Name        = $Profile.Name
      LastLogon   = $Profile.LastWriteTime
      ProfilePath = $Profile.GetValue('ProfileImagePath')
  }
  $Profile
}
...
```

Also, You're retrieving the **`LastWriteTime`** of a registry key and then labeling it as **`LastLogon`**. I think that's faulty logic.

Comment: Keith - Thanks. Think there is a typo in your answer (Get-Member), important for those not familiar with Powershell cmdlet names, but not sure you can edit out something so basic. Good idea to use Get-Member (wish I had thought of it)... So I guess your saying, in other words, that what looked like a Object with properties was in fact a formatted string that output like the aforementioned? Lastly, I have read that the only reliable way of telling lastlogon time on the current system is via obtaining LastWriteTime from the base HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList key.

Comment: II'm not sure what you're saying is a formatted stiring. Re-read this part of the linked reference: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/samples/working-with-registry-entries?view=powershell-7#listing-registry-entries

Comment: I'll take your word for it on last logon.

Comment: Keith - Nevermind about what it is actually called. No need to take my word for it - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28959160/wrong-lastlogon-returned-from-win32-networkloginprofile/45176943#45176943